# How do I know if a plugin supports Craft 3.1's project config?

Tags: plugins, projectconfig

Craft version 3.1 introduced the [project config](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/project-config.html) file.

The documentation mentions "plugins may not support it yet:"

> Any plugins that are storing configuration settings outside of their main plugin settings will need to be updated to support the project config. So there may still be some cases where changes need to be manually made on each environment.

Is there any way to know if a plugin for Craft 3 supports project config files?

Answer (score 2):

The best I could find was searching thru a plugin's changelog in the [Craft Plugin Store](https://plugins.craftcms.com) for something like "Added support for Craft 3.1 project config."

[Super Table version 2.1.1](https://plugins.craftcms.com/super-table#2.1.1):

- Added support for Craft 3.1 project config.

[Redactor version 2.2.0](https://plugins.craftcms.com/redactor#2.2.0):

- Redactor for Craft CMS now requires Craft 3.1.
- Improved Project Config compatibility.